# R посчитать количество заказов для продавца

Tags: r, count, order

> Есть таблица со столбцами:
>
> 1. Комментарий - содержит номер заказа или номера заказов, может содержать что-то другое. Примеры: Заказ - 12345678, пара заказов - 12345678, 87654321, и что-то другое тоже может быть.
> 2. Электронная почта продавца.
>
> Задача посчитать количество заказов для каждого продавца. Вывести все номера заказов для каждого продавца.
> Пример данных:
> dt <- data.frame(names=c("Екатерина","Матвей","Анастасия", "Татьяна", "Владимир", "Татьяна"), orders=c("#","51234567", "1111111", "+79371112233", "33", "51234568"))

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1.

```
res <- tapply(df$orders, df$names, function(x) {
    list(count = length(unique(x)),
         orders = paste(x, collapse = ", "))
})
do.call(rbind, res)
#>           count orders                  
#> Анастасия 1     "1111111"               
#> Владимир  1     "33"                    
#> Екатерина 1     "#"                     
#> Матвей    1     "51234567"              
#> Татьяна   2     "+79371112233, 51234568"
```

Вариант 2.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(names) %>% 
    summarise(count = n_distinct(orders),
              orders = paste(orders, collapse = ", "))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   names     count orders                
#>   <chr>     <int> <chr>                 
#> 1 Анастасия     1 1111111               
#> 2 Владимир      1 33                    
#> 3 Екатерина     1 #                     
#> 4 Матвей        1 51234567              
#> 5 Татьяна       2 +79371112233, 51234568
```

Вариант 3.

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, .(count = uniqueN(orders), orders = paste(orders, collapse = ", ")), by = names]
#>        names count                 orders
#> 1: Екатерина     1                      #
#> 2:    Матвей     1               51234567
#> 3: Анастасия     1                1111111
#> 4:   Татьяна     2 +79371112233, 51234568
#> 5:  Владимир     1                     33
```

Comment: Это чума, вышло по первому варианту. Со вторым что-то не получилось.
Теперь есть другая проблема, если поможете буду безмерно благодарен.
Одна результирующая строчка такая:
Менеджер     Заказов     Номера заказов
Анастасия           1         "59953630, 59953630" 

Проблема в том, что ранее в таблице было сразу два заказа указано, может Вы подскажите как посчитать число вхождений в текст с помощью grep?